# React-Native OnPress event in Svg-Pattern

Tags: react-native, svg, expo, ontouch

Is it possible to add a `OnPress` event inside a Svg/Pattern/Rect element? I am trying to make clickable cells inside a grid like this:

```
<Pattern
  id="Grid"
  patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  width="50" // polygon.scale * 10 ? 
  height="50" // polygon.scale * 10 ? 
  viewBox="0 0 100 100"
  >
  <Rect width="100" height="100" fill="red" stroke="black" onPress={() =>  
    alert('Press on Circle')} />
</Pattern>
```

What other options are there?

Comment: You didn't say but I asume that you are using react-native-svg, from what I can get it doesn't define any onPress 

If that the case according to their documentation onPress is supported

Comment: Hi Cristian,  yes RN-svg. It's works on unnested elements, but it seems not inside a pattern element. Any solution or trick?